# Problem with configuring format Python Logger

Tags: python, logging

If I set `logging.basicConfig(level=INFO, filename="...")`, the only thing I am going to see is the actual message I have put inside `logger.info("...").`

For example if I write:

`logger.info("blah blah blah")`

What I am going to see in Console is:

`blah blah blah`

What I want to see is the program line number of logger.info as well.
Something like if let's say `logger.info` is at line 64 at main.py:

`line number 64 main.py: blah blah blah`

What I should change to see this in the logger setting of python?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Python logging formatters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#formatter-objects) to do something like this:

```py
import logging

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(format='{%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d}: %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

    logging.info('test')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

which outputs

```
{test.py:6}: test
```